DOS (density of states) in the vicinity of a band extremum point
If we consider the DOS for a band:
$$\rho_\nu(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{V_{BZ}}\int_{BZ}\delta(\epsilon-E_{\vec k,\nu})d\vec k$$
Why is it that the DOS changes in the vicinity of the extrema points of of the band,corresponding to $\vec k_0$:
$\rho_\nu(\epsilon)=const.\sqrt{\epsilon -E_{\vec k_0,\nu}} \vec k_0$ (minimum)
$\rho_\nu(\epsilon)=const.\sqrt{E_{(\vec k_0,\nu} - \epsilon)} \vec k_0$ (maximum).
For example, in the Wikipedia article about the Density of states, something similar happens when one considers the state of highest energy in the valence band.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states

It doesn't change, it's just that you're simplifying by approximating the density of states as parabolic near an extremum. Note that (in 1D for simplicity)
$$\int_{BZ} \delta\big(\epsilon- E(k)\big) \ \mathrm dk = \int_{BZ} \delta\big(k -  E^{-1}(\epsilon)\big) \frac{\mathrm dk}{\left|E'(k)\right|}$$
by the properties of the delta function. If $E(k) = E_0 + \frac{1}{2}k^2$ (i.e. we are interested in the neighborhood of a minimum), then $E'(k) =k$ and $E^{-1}(\epsilon) = \pm 2\sqrt{\epsilon-E_0}$ and so
$$D_{\mathrm{1D}}(\epsilon) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \delta\big(\epsilon- E(k)\big) \mathrm dk = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left(\frac{1}{\left|2\sqrt{\epsilon-E_0}\right|}+ \frac{1}{\left|-2\sqrt{\epsilon-E_0}\right|}\right)= \frac{1}{8\pi\sqrt{\epsilon-E_0}}$$
The calculation changes in 3D, leading to $D_{\mathrm{3D}}(\epsilon)\propto \sqrt{\epsilon-E_0}$.

But should the integration change from over the Bz to the k-space? Also, in the 3D case, would using a taylor expansion of the energy around the energy value that corresponds to the maximum be  appropriate ?

@imbAF The Brillouin zone is the k-space, so the integration region doesn't change. I'm not sure I understand your second question - you can approximate the dispersion relation about any point that you like.
